# Eloquent Where In With Join Subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to do this query in Laravel 5.4 with Eloquent and I do not get the subquery to function as it should. This is the original SQL query:

```
select * from projects p
        inner join projects_categories pc on p.id = pc.project_id
where pc.name in (select pc.name from projects p
                      inner join projects_categories pc on p.id = pc.project_id
                  where p.id = $project->id) and p.id <> $project->id;
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 Project::join('projects_categories', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_categories.project_id')
        ->whereIn([
            ['projects_categories.name', function ($query) {
            $query->select('projects_categories.name')
                ->from('projects')
                ->join('projects_categories', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_categories.project_id')
                ->where('project.id', '=', $project->id);
        }],
            ['projects.id', '<>', $project->id]
        ])
    ->get();
```

But all the time I get the error back:

Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereIn().

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Project::join('projects_categories', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_categories.project_id')
->whereIn('projects_categories.name', function($query) use($project) {
    $query->select('projects_categories.name')->from('projects')
    ->join('projects_categories', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_categories.project_id')
    ->where('projects.id', '=', $project->id);
})->where('projects.id', '<>', $project->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If in `Project.php` you have a `hasMany` relationship for `categories` i.e

```
public function categories() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class); 
}
```

Then you should be able to return the relationship eloquently like so:

```
Project::find($id)->with('categories');
```

Or if you already have a project object loaded

```
$project->load('categories');
```

I would checkout the Laravel documentation as the join you posted looks overly complicated!

Comment: Yes, really the optimal situation is how you comment, but what I need is a very specific case in which that query is required. Anyway, thanks for your help !!

Comment: does this relationship method work if we not defined relationship and forignkey?

Comment: In this scenario, you have to have a defined relationship on the `Project` model called `categoories`. If you aren't using eloquent relationships, then you aren't really getting the main benefit of using the Laravel framework (in my opinion anyway)